# How do I open a new window on start up using C++?

Tags: c++, windows

I don't know how to make a window when I start up Windows. I just want a simple window that has some text in it, such as a reminder. I don't want to download anything, and I think C++ is the easiest way to do it.

Answer (score 4):

The easiest way to display a window with a message in Windows would be use use VBScript.  Create a text file with the following in it.

```
msgbox("hello world")
```

Now, name the file MyProgram.vbs or anything else with a .vbs extension.

Double click on the file to run it. The message "hello world" should be shown in a small window on your screen. As seen in the image below.

[image]

To run it at start up, just drag it in your Startup folder in your Start Menu.